# Inner class allows static fields and non constant static expression - Why?

Tags: java, inner-classes

As per JLS :

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static. Inner classes may not declare static initializers
>    or member interfaces.

But my following code is compiling successfully.

```
class A {
    interface B { 
        class C { // Inner class having static variables.
            static int d; // Static variable
            static {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior

Comment: I'm pretty sure `C` is implicitly `static`, opposed to being a inner class.

Comment: Your nested class **is** implicitly declared static. Because interfaces can't have inner classes. Same for the interface B, which is implicitly static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found JLS specifications for the same :

> 8.5.2 - "Member interfaces are always implicitly static"
>
> 9.5 - "Interfaces may contain member type declarations (§8.5). A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly static and
>   public"

This means code above is morally equivalent to (implicit modifiers are written in capitalized letters):

```
class A {
    STATIC interface B {
        PUBLIC STATIC class C { //It's a static class - that's why static members are legal (like a toplevel class but nested)
            static int d; //Static variable
            static {} //Static initializer

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested interfaces are implicitly static and do not have a non-static context themselves, that's why C is implicitly static.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class inside an interface. Inside the interface, the inner class is implicitly public static. ... Interfaces may contain member type declarations  A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly static and public.

so we can not declare **non-static** members into a **static block**, **static method** or **static class**.